# Universal number comparer

Tags: c#

I wrote some code which compares numbers of all datatypes with each other.
The standard Comparer which is implemented by every number Type only compares numbers of the same type.

I cast to decimal because this is the largest possible number type and should cover everything.

1. What do you think about the code?
2. Is there any room for improvement?
3. How can I handle NaN the best way?
4. Do you think BigInt and Real numbers should be a part of it?

```
public class UniversalNumberComparer: IComparer
{
    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        if(!IsNumber(x) || !IsNumber(y))
            throw new InvalidOperationException();

        if(x == null) 
        {
            return y == null
                ? 0
                : -1;
        }
        else
        {
            if(y == null)
                return 1;
        }

        return Decimal.Compare(Convert.ToDecimal(x), Convert.ToDecimal(y));
    }

    private bool IsNumber(object value)
    {
        if(value is sbyte || value is sbyte?)
            return true;
        if(value is byte || value is byte?)
            return true;
        if(value is short || value is short?)
            return true;
        if(value is ushort || value is ushort?)
            return true;
        if(value is int || value is int?)
            return true;
        if(value is uint || value is uint?)
            return true;
        if(value is long || value is long?)
            return true;
        if(value is ulong || value is ulong?)
            return true;
        if(value is float || value is float?)
            return true;
        if(value is double || value is double?)
            return true;
        if(value is decimal || value is decimal?)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you even tried your code? It won't work unless both values are `decimal`. Also, what about `BigInteger`?

Comment: fixed.
BigInt is part of the question. At the moment i only handle basic types at the moment.

Comment: Where do you see yourself needing this object?  Generally, you should be comparing two numbers of the same type.  Exceptions to this rule should be few enough that you should handle (and comment) it where needed rather than coming up with a general-purpose class.  Needing to create a general-purpose class to compare separate number types, particularly in a type-unsafe manner reeks of code smells elsewhere.

Comment: [Determine if type is numeric](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/124411/using-net-how-can-i-determine-if-a-type-is-a-numeric-valuetype)   should be very helpful

Comment: @DanLyons The point is to have a comparer for a generic list<object> which orders the content by the values of the numbers.
And... in an Assert Helper class wich test if a number value is in between 2 other values without knowing the type and without writing tons of overloads and generics make no much sense here either

Comment: @radarbob Thanks for the link i will check it out

Comment: Whenever you write code, there should be a reason to do it. Treating the code as good or bad, or considering possible improvements only makes sense if there's context of problem you're trying to solve. If there's not problem your code solves, it's just useless.

Comment: @loki2302 I would not have asked for a code review if there is no reason for me to have this code. This was not an academic example but is used.

Comment: I'm not saying it has no reason to exist, I'm saying it's impossible to tell if its good or bad unless you unveil the problem you're solving: first, the problem, then solution.

Answer (score 6):

As for your question about NaN: this is also a situation where conversion to decimal is likely to be problematic. Assuming that you resolve that problem, the question then is what to do about it in the comparison.

It depends on the goals of your comparison. The semantics of NaN are "this thing isn't even a number, so asking which one is bigger is a nonsensical question", and therefore any operation on NaN is false. That means that NaN is *not* greater than any number, *not* smaller than any number and *not* equal to any number, including itself. If that's acceptable for your comparison purposes then that's the semantics you should implement.

Those semantics are **not acceptable for sorting**. If the comparison is being used in a comparison sort then the comparison is required to produce a *total consistent order*. It must be *reflexive* -- every number must equal itself. It must be *antisymmetric* -- if a < b is true then b < a must be false. And it must be *transitive* -- if a < b is true and b < c is true then a < c must be true. The usual way to deal with NaNs is to say that all NaNs are equal to each other -- achieving reflexivity, and that all NaNs are smaller than every non-NaN -- achieving antisymmetry and transitivity.

And don't forget that you'll need to deal with positive and negative infinities.

Comment: Thanks Eric. I already felt that casting to decimal is not the way to go. The Comparer as i posted does it for me at the moment and my project. BUT i really want to make it work considering all possible cases (Negatives, NAN, nullables,...). To be honest, i expected this task as much easier then it turned out to be.

Answer (score 5):

> I cast to decimal because this is the largest possible number type and should cover everything.

Since this statement uses fallacious reasoning, and the correctness of the code depends on this statement being sound, the code is unlikely to be correct. *Just because decimal takes up the most bytes doesn't mean that every value of every other numeric type can be represented in decimal.*

Presumably you would like your numeric comparer to have the property that if, say, 10<sup>200</sup> and 10<sup>210</sup> are passed in as doubles, that the one which is *ten billion times larger* would be considered larger. What actually happens?

And presumably you would like to have the property that if say, 10<sup>-200</sup> and 10<sup>-210</sup> are passed in as doubles, that the one which is *ten billion times smaller* would be considered smaller. What actually happens?

Answer (score 3):

Some thoughts:

- There's no point in testing whether `x` or `y` is null, because when `null` is passed, `IsNumber()` returns `false`.
- If you do want to keep that code, perhaps by modifying `IsNumber()` to accept `null`, then you should organize that if/else tree better.  Standard structure is to either `return` from every branch of the tree, not `return` from the tree at all, or (for purposes of error checking) not have an `else` clause at all.  You're using an `if`/`else` pair, with a nested ternary operator (`? :`) **and** another nested `if`.  It's just a confusing jumble.
- Exhaustive lists like in `IsNumber()` are generally a bad idea, but in this case I think it's acceptable.  I have no opinion between lots of individual test/return pairs vs a single giant test.  However, there's no point to testing the nullable cases - once you've converted to an `object` ("boxing"), a null value looses the type it had had, and anything else is simply the type of its value.  You would have to explicitly cast it *back* to a nullable in order to set it to `null`.

Comment: I think the point about `is int?` could use some elaboration: There is no such thing as boxed nullable value. Boxing (i.e. converting to `object`) of nullable value results either in `null` or in the underlying type (e.g. `int`) boxed.

Comment: @svick - Good to know.  I knew that it behaved that way, but I had no idea why.  I'll edit in a bit more about that.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment of "radarbob", you could redefine your IsNumber() to:

```
private static bool IsNumber(object value)
{
    return TypeCodes.Contains(Type.GetTypeCode(value.GetType()));
}

private static readonly List<TypeCode> TypeCodes = new List<TypeCode>
{
    TypeCode.Byte,
    TypeCode.Decimal,
    TypeCode.Double,
    TypeCode.Int16,
    TypeCode.Int32,
    TypeCode.Int64,
    TypeCode.SByte,
    TypeCode.Single,
    TypeCode.UInt16,
    TypeCode.UInt32,
    TypeCode.UInt64,
};
```

And as "Bobson" mentioned, mixing the ternary operator and nested if/else structures is messy. Keep it with an if/else structure or you could try this:

```
public int Compare(object x, object y)
{
    if(!IsNumber(x) || !IsNumber(y))
        throw new InvalidOperationException();

    return x == null
        ? (y == null ? 0 : -1)
        : (y == null ? 1 : Decimal.Compare(Convert.ToDecimal(x), Convert.ToDecimal(y)));
}
```

Comment: I don't find that use of ternary particularly clear, but it's still better than the mess of conventions in the OP.  It's easy enough to read through it and see what it does, but it isn't intuitively obvious.